# Interpolation of data which follows some criteria

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I want to replace the positive values in the slope column with the interpolation of the previous values.

For example : If Slope = [-5,-3,10,-4,-1] then the entry 10 should become -1.

All the values in the Slope Column must be negative or 0

My Attempt:

```
    df[df['Slope']>0] = df['Slope'].interpolate()
```

Since I am relatively new to Python, sorry if this question is too basic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the values over 0 to `nan` first then you can `interpolate`:

```
df[df["Slope"]>0] = np.NaN

print (df.interpolate())

   Slope
0   -5.0
1   -3.0
2   -3.5
3   -4.0
4   -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is dependant on what type of interpolation you want.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

The docs list out what types of interpolation pandas can do, it is linear by default so you would get -3.5 as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `interpolate` works with `Nan` you have to convert your positive values to `Nan`.
Then you have to group your rows
Finally you can use `interpolate(method="spline",order=1))`.

```
df.loc[df["Slope"]>0, "Slope"] = np.nan
df["Slope_grp"] = (df["Slope"].shift().isna() &d f["Slope"].notnull()).cumsum()
df["Slope_new"] = df.groupby("Slope_grp")["Slope"].apply(lambda x:x.interpolate(method="spline",order=1))

print(df)
   Slope  Slope_grp  Slope_new
0   -5.0          1       -5.0
1   -3.0          1       -3.0
2    NaN          1       -1.0
3   -4.0          2       -4.0
4   -1.0          2       -1.0
```

It also works if you have more than one consecutive positive value:

```
   Slope  Slope_grp  Slope_new
0   -5.0          1       -5.0
1   -3.0          1       -3.0
2    NaN          1       -1.0
3    NaN          1        1.0
4    NaN          1        3.0
5   -4.0          2       -4.0
6   -1.0          2       -1.0
```